# Mssql and Mvc, mail scheduling is required

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, triggers

I have a database created in mssql with column last reviewed,if last reviewed column value is not changed for more than 5 days , user need to get mail saying action is pending.

Comment: What version and Edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Create a table and give some input and describe the question bit more detail.

Comment: using mssql 2014

Comment: I have Database name as register and database table as dbo.Idea and column as Idea_Last_Reviewed, once idea is submitted, Idea go to pending status in Idea_Status column, if the reviewer doesnt review Idea in 5 days mail has to be send for Manger saying action is pending, i have Manager_Login_ID column in dbo.Idea Table also

Comment: i have written this code, but mail is triggered even condition fails:
BEGIN
    select
Manager_login_id
from
login
where
Login_id in (
  select
    Login_id
  from
    Idea
  where
   Idea_Date_Of_Submission >= Datediff(dd, 5, getdate()) 
) 
  END

Comment: and mail has to be sent to resulted manager login id wich display when query is excuted