# Mssql, Mvc c#, Mail trigger,

Tags: c#, sql-server, email, model-view-controller

I Need a C# code,or mssql trigger .i have a column in database (Idea_Date_Of_Submission), i want code if the Idea_Date_Of_Submission is greater than 5 days, user logged in should get a mail saying action is pending, i have a column by name idea_status

Comment: the user must be logged in to get the mail?

Comment: no , user must not be logged in. actually, kind of idea submission site, there are 4 reviewers who review idea, if any of the reviewer doesn't review idea within 5 days from date of submission then , the reviewer should receive mail saying action pending

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As this is not a code-writing service, have a look here at how to ask an MCVE question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can assist

Comment: I'd suggest a view then either a SSIS or other scheduled task with the ability to send mail. What have you tried Ashok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mssql and Mvc, mail scheduling is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607891/mssql-and-mvc-mail-scheduling-is-required)

Comment: So you have done nothing since yesterday and your previous question.

Answer (score 2):

So as there is no complicated business required, only filtering you don't need c# code, you need to use only SQL Server Jobs.

To That You Need to Define A job which contains your business using SQL Server Agent Link Below :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

Inside the Job you need to setup the email :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Here is Also tutorial step by Step : https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/send-query-results-sql-server-agent-job/.

And Example for your query will be :

```
SELECT Manager_Login_ID  FROM dbo.Idea
WHERE Idea_Last_Reviewed <= DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE()) and Idea_Status = 'Pending';
```

Comment: Hi Hany Habib , can you please help me to write query for this:I have Database name as register and database table as dbo.Idea and column as Idea_Last_Reviewed, once idea is submitted, Idea go to pending status in Idea_Status column, if the reviewer doesnt review Idea in 5 days mail has to be send for Manger saying action is pending, i have Manager_Login_ID column in dbo.Idea Table also

Comment: you have examples in the links that you just need to copy and paste nothing more. Hope helped, if yes dont forget to mark the answer

Comment: i used below code 
SELECT Manager_Login_ID  FROM dbo.Idea
WHERE Idea_Date_Of_Submission <= DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE()) and Idea_Status = 'Pending';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        profile_name = 'ashokamz',
        recipients = '',
        body = 'The DB has changed',
        subject = 'DB Change';
  i used above code, but according to condition if above condition satisfies it needs to send mail else it shouldn't and even if column value is null it shouldn't send mail but here mail is sent always if condition is satisfied and not satisfied also

Comment: @AshokHoskera code in comments is terrible because of the lack of formatting. But you don't seem to have any logic there. Probably want an IF statement.

Comment: i am not able to write after  Idea_Status = 'Pending'; by giving condition for if table value is null dont send mail and exec send mail. can u please help me to write query